# Check radiobuttons after SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader, getstring

I have 2 radio buttons in a panel and I save their value as numeric (0 and 1) here is the code for insert into SQL:

```
String typdop="1";
if(rb_a.Checked)typdop="0";
("INSERT INTO zajezd(typdop)values(@typdop")
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("typdop", typdop);
```

and for reading I use this:

```
SqlCommand novyprikaz = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce="+nc_zajezd_vyber, spojeni); 
con.Open();
SqlDataReader precti = novyprikaz.ExecuteReader();

if (precti.Read())
{
     try
     {  rb_a.Checked = precti(32);}
```

the visual studio gives me an error, because I don't know how to change Checked value of `rb_a`, I would like to read it like this:

If in database is saved `0` - Check `rb_a`

If `1` I would like to check `rb_b`

May someone help solve this out?
Thanks

Comment: Please fix your code. Something is missing. (Remember to add 4 spaces before any code statement)

Comment: Checked is bool field, so fill it with boolean -> true, false

Comment: Get some using blocks in there are well. using(SqlDataRreader reader = novyprikaz.ExecuteReader() {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many details are missing, but you could try this code.

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM zajezd WHERE akce=@p1";
SqlCommand novyprikaz = new SqlCommand(cmdText, spojeni); 
novyprikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", nc_zajezd_vyber);
spojeni.Open(); 
SqlDataReader precti = novyprikaz.ExecuteReader();
if (precti.Read())
{
   try
   {  
        bool check = Convert.ToBoolean(precti(32));
        if(check) 
            rb_b.Checked = true;
        else
            rb_a.Checked = true;
   }
}
```

Please take note; if your `nc_zajezd_vyber` is not of the correct datatype required by the database field, your query could fail to retrieve anything. AddWithValue assumes the datatype of the parameter from the value passed. If this is not correct....

For the same reasong (AddWithValue wants the exact datatype expected by the database field, then your insert code should be something like this:

```
int typdop=1; 
if(rb_a.Checked) typdop=0; 
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO zajezd(typdop)values(@typdop)"; 
SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand(cmdText,spojeni);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("typdop", typdop);
spojeni.Open();
prikaz.ExecuteNonQuery();
....
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it read like if (typdop (this is the column in sql) == 0) {rb_a.Checked} else {rb_b.Checked} and put this code into SqlDataReader? But anyway thanks for helping!